# Can I add a function with the (click) event to my span tags that I added with the replace method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular12

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5doW.png
I have sentences like this, and as you can see, if the word I'm looking for is in that sentence, I put it in span tags.

```
.replace(query.toLocaleLowerCase(), `<span>${query}</span>`,).toLocaleLowerCase()
```

(query is my search word)
and I want to make the word taken in these span tags like this

```
`<span (click)="myFunction()">${query}</span>`
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution like this, it's not quite right, but the simplest

TS Side

```
click(evt) {
const href = evt.target.localName;

if (href == 'span') {
  evt.path.forEach(element => {
    if (element.localName == "p") {
       ---my codes---
    }
  });
}
```

}

HTML side;

```
(click)="click($event)" [innerHtml]="subtitle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
.replace(query.toLocaleLowerCase(), `<span onclick="functionName()">${query}</span>`,).toLocaleLowerCase()
```

Comment: yes but it doesn't work

Comment: use the "inspect element" and see if your span tag has the onlick attribute